# Efficiently modifying a html output stream

Tags: node.js, express, stream

I have static files that I can't directly modify that are on disk. I'm servicing them with the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.listen(3000);
```

Need to modify the outgoing stream to add an element into the start of the `<head>` or if the `<head>` isn't present before we see the `<body>`, create a head, add the element and put it in before the `<body>`.

I know I can tap `http`s output stream but I'm having trouble in modifying the stream in an efficient/performant manner. Any thoughts around doing this?

Comment: Looks like you want to include a custom script into every served file. Is there any reason you want to make this on the fly again and again for every request? Why not making it once in the FS before starting the server?

Comment: In this case I can't update the underlying files, it has to be as they are streamed out.